# Getting error when updating to 5.61.2

Tags: upgrade, joomla

I have CiviCRM version 5.41.2 running on Joomla and I'm trying to upgrade to 5.61.2

I have followed the upgrade guide here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/

But when I get to "Upgrade the database" I'm getting an error shown:

```
Declaration of CRM_Custom_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess()
must be compatible with CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess(): void

...\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Custom\Import\Form\Summary.php:13
```

If I look at the above file, on line 13 is as follows:

```
13     public function preProcess() {
14     parent::preProcess();
15     $session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();
16     $session->pushUserContext(CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/import/custom', 'reset=1'));
17   }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the notes after step 4 at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/#install-the-extension. The joomla upgrade process is flawed when files are removed from civi. Remove that Summary.php file manually.

You may also want to remove the other files deleted in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/ff2119386936d603d226631ee081e06855f9a1cb, or do a complete civi folder removal and replace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done all of that but now getting another error "Undefined variable: store" in \administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Permission\Joomla.php:56

Comment: You'll see a lot of warnings like that. They'll need to be addressed in core but as long as things are working you can ignore them for now. The fix for that one is to just change line 56 so instead of `$store` it says `NULL`.